# Look for files in a directory (on Putty environment) which do not have a string

Tags: unix

I need to look for files in a library first which do not have a string in it. Then out of the resulting file names I need to search for files with a string.

To begin with, I tried grep -L on my command line but it doesn't work.
I'm pretty new to unix, can anyone please help in building this logic.

Thanks!

Comment: ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Can someone pls share views on this one, i've been stuck here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas and cmds to search for.

(Your problem description is unclear to me, so I'm giving you what seems like the most likely solution you are asking for)..

Given a test file

```
echo "a
b
c
d" > /tmp/testFile.txt
```

you can search for a "word" (or character) in that file with

```
grep d /tmp/testFile.txt ; echo $?
```

which will return

```
 d
 0
```

`0` indicates a successfully executed cmd, while `1` (or other non-zero value) indicates a error occurred.

Now add the `-l` option to `grep` which says "list" the files that meet the requirements of the options supplied:

```
 grep -l e /tmp/testFile.txt ; echo $?
```

returns only

```
 1
```

Because `e` was not found in the file, it's name was not printed.

By contrast, searching for a string that does exist in the file looks like

```
grep -l d /tmp/testFile.txt ; echo $?

/tmp/testFile.txt
0
```

indicating the search target was found.

---

Now you need a way to get a list of all files to search on grep,

```
cd /path/to/starting/dir/to/search  # you know what to put here, right?
find . -name '*.txt'
```

will produce a list of all `.txt` files in the current directory and in all sub-directories of the current directory.

Finally, you can feed the list of `.txt` files to a loop that can check if your target string exists or not

```
srchStr="e"
cd /path/to/starting/dir/to/search  # you know what to put here, right?
find . -name '*.txt' \
| while read file ; do 
    if ! grep -q "$srchStr" "$file" ; then 
      echo "no $srchStr in $file"
   fi  
done
```

Of course this won't meet your needs. But please post a new Q with some code, and others may be able to help you. I can't spend more time on this (any time soon). Look for tutorials on `unix find`, which is key to listing all files so you can then search thru them with grep.

IHTH